# Json data from Guardian API

Tags: javascript, json, web-scraping

I have a guardian json data feed that I want to pull into my page online.

http://content.guardianapis.com/world/cuba?format=json&show-fields=trail-text%2Cheadline&order-by=newest&api-key=c3rr449rqqebmuxua9k5mdcz

I have used this javascript but nothing seems to be working to grab the right content from the json;

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: false,
    url: "http://content.guardianapis.com/world/cuba?format=json&show-fields=trail-text%2Cheadline&order-by=newest&api-key=c3rr449rqqebmuxua9k5mdcz",
    success: function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        $("#cuban-news").append("<div class='guardian'><a target='_blank' href='" + webTitle + "'>Link</a></div>");
        }
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

});

This is not throwing anything in terms of errors.

Am I better using a js service like backbone or underscore?

Any help would be amazing on this.

Comment: Does the Guardian support JSONP and not just regular JSON? Remember it needs to wrap the JSON in a callback in order to return it.

Comment: @Lloyd — Yes. Just tested that.

Comment: *This is not throwing anything in terms of errors* — Yes, it is: `Uncaught ReferenceError: webTitle is not defined`

Comment: yes it does support callback. I am just wondering/struggling to get the data onto the page as there are so many data levels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
data.response.results[i].webTitle
```

instead of

```
webTitle
```

error was
*Uncaught ReferenceError: webTitle is not defined*

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: false,
    url: "http://content.guardianapis.com/world/cuba?format=json&show-fields=trail-text%2Cheadline&order-by=newest&api-key=c3rr449rqqebmuxua9k5mdcz",
    success: function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.response.results.length; i++) {
        $("#cuban-news").append("<div class='guardian'><a target='_blank' href='" 
            + data.response.results[i].webTitle + "'>Link</a></div>");
            }
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
 });​
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QrwfL/)

Comment: ah ah, it was the origin of the data that was getting to me, I kept looking at starting with object which was wrong. I looked at the console log for that in the data. Thanks a bunch!